# JPA entity composite primery key not saving to the database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing such kind of issue. I have this code base. This is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "your_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEntityId id;

    @Column(name = "other_data")
    private String otherData;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And this one is the composite primery key part in java code,

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEntityId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id1")
    private Long id1;

    @Column(name = "id2")
    private Long id2;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Here is the repository part to save that entity

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, MyEntityId> {}
```

this one is the service layer:

```
@Service
public class MyEntityService {

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repository;

    public void saveEntity(MyEntity entity) {
        repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of saving the record to the database:

```
   1. final MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
   2. entity.setId(new MyEntityId("id_1", "e56962a6-4747-49cd-b67b-bf8b01975c4c"));
   3. final List<MyEntity> got = repository.findAll();
   4. final MyEntity saved = repository.save(entity);
```

The interesting part here is that, when executing the line 3, it gets the previously saved list, and when executing the line 4, it normally passes that line, without any error, but no new records are being saved in the database.
Also in the log section I see that there are only two selects after line 4, but no insert is present there.
Any ideas of what can be the reason of this weird behavior?

Comment: Did you try this in a transactional context? Also, it would be helpful to have the full code sample of what seems to be the service.
I suspect the reason might have to do with detached entities, which might get dropped when doing the findAll.

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm also trying this with @Transactional annotation on method, calling this repository, but results are the same.
2. The same code is tested without the findAll method call, it's just a demostration for finding out that read operation works, but write, no.

Answer (score 0):

Just created my little test, and when using a composite key if nothing changes on the entity, then there is no reason for the entity to get inserted or updated, hence no update or insert in logs.

Try changing anything on your entity e.g. other_data and you will see an update getting triggered. If you change any of the composite keys, an insert statement will be done.